# clear a label that is ran by the server with the browser

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, label

I need to show only one error message at a time I am trying to get the `<asp:RequiredFieldValidator>`and the `<asp:RangeValidator>` to display a message after it clears the label from the server side 
if I trigger the server to produce the message then trigger the browser through the Validators it does not remove or replace the server side even though it is only one label 
this is what I get as a result 
 [image]

this is my C# code .aspx.cs file

```
        protected void btnIncident_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataView customersTable = (DataView)SqlDataSource1.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
        customersTable.RowFilter = "CustomerID = '" + txtCusID.Text + "'";
        if (customersTable.Count>=1)
        {
            DataRowView row = customersTable[0];
            DataView incidentTable = (DataView)SqlDataSource2.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
            incidentTable.RowFilter = "CustomerID = '" + txtCusID.Text + "' AND DateClosed IS NOT NULL";
            if (incidentTable.Count>0)
            {
                lstContact.Items.Clear();
                lblCusIDError.Text = "";
                for (int i = 0; i< incidentTable.Count; i++)
                {
                    DataRowView row1 = incidentTable[i];
                    incident = new Incident();
                    incident.IncidentID = (int)row1["IncidentID"];
                    incident.CustomerID = (int)row1["CustomerID"];
                    incident.ProductCode = row1["ProductCode"].ToString();
                    incident.TechID = (int)row1["TechID"];
                    incident.DateOpened = (DateTime)row1["DateOpened"];
                    incident.DateClosed = (DateTime)row1["DateClosed"];
                    incident.Title = row1["Title"].ToString();
                    lstContact.Items.Add(new ListItem( incident.CustomerIncidentDisplay(), (incident.IncidentID).ToString()));
                }
                lstContact.Enabled = true;
            }
            else
            {
                lblCusIDError.Text = "";
                lblCusIDError.Text = "ID: " + txtCusID.Text + " has "+incidentTable.Count+" closed incident case.";
            }

        }
        else
        {
            lblCusIDError.Text = "ID: " + txtCusID.Text + " does not exist.";
        }


    }
```

then i have this in aspx file

```
                    <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="txtCusID" class="control-label col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-0 lblName" >Enter your customer ID: </label>
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                      <asp:TextBox ID="txtCusID" CssClass="form-control" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvCusID" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtCusID" CssClass="text-danger lblName" ErrorMessage="You must enter a Customer ID." Display="Dynamic"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        <asp:RangeValidator ID="rvCusID" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtCusID" CssClass="text-danger lblName" Type="Integer" MinimumValue="1000" MaximumValue="9999" ErrorMessage="Customer ID must be within 1000 and 9999" Display="Dynamic"></asp:RangeValidator>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblCusIDError" runat="server" CssClass="text-danger lblName" ></asp:Label>
                        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>' SelectCommand="SELECT [CustomerID], [Name] FROM [Customers] ORDER BY [CustomerID]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                      <asp:Button ID="btnIncident" Text="Get Incidents" CssClass="btn-sm col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-0" runat="server" OnClick="btnIncident_Click"></asp:Button>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: Why do you use a label as a custom validation message instead using... `<asp:CustomValidator>`?

Comment: because i need to  use the server to reach the database

Comment: The CustomValidator can have a server side method. You a reinventing the wheel